# Is it possible to change state (update the address bar) and only reload a particular view with Angular's ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an application with Angular and ui-router. I have a layout that has a search pane on the right, and a content pane to show search results. In the search pane's controller, I've been using a shared service that sets search parameters. In the content controller, I import this same service and have a watch for when its properties change. If you look at the layout below, you'll see that users can enter a search term, as well as filter results with dropdown criteria. The filters allow for refining search results by market(1)/division(2)/category(3).

[image: Application Layout]

This setup has worked for the last couple months without issues. However, now I want to add search history, so if a user searches with a term, or filters by category, the address bar is updated with `/:searchTerm?categoryId=foo`. I have a state setup for this in my ui-router config:

```
.state('app.search', {
    url: '/search/:searchTerm?categoryId&attributes',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/search_results.html',
    controller: 'SearchResultsController'
})
```

This works and I'm able to retain the search history as desired. However, I'm using `$state.go` in my SearchController to update the URL in the address bar and I've noticed both my panes (search and content) get reloaded. Is it possible to change state (update the address bar) and only reload the content pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to split your state into two states:

```
.state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    template: '<div ui-view></div><div>search bar</div>',
    controller: 'SearchController'
})

.state('app.search.results', {
    url: '/:searchTerm?categoryId&attributes',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/search_results.html',
    controller: 'SearchResultsController'
})
```

So the first state has a template that contains a view for the results and the actual search sidebar.

This way you just need to call`$state.go('app.search.results', {...})` from the your SearchController and it should only update the sub view as you only change parameters of that view.